# Слишком много весит плагин Appodeal для Phonegap

Tags: phonegap, cordova

В процессе добавления рекламы в приложение на Cordova столкнулся с проблемой - подгружая официальный плагин SDK(**cordova plugin add https://github.com/appodeal/appodeal-cordova-plugin.git**), увидел, что он весит более 500 мб (В основном адаптеры рекламных сетей для iOS) - при сборке, соответственно, получается очень тяжелое приложение (даже для android собирается apk около 30 Mb - при том что само мое приложение примерно 2 Мб, а для iOS все 500).

Подскажите те, кто уже собирал phonegap-приложение с рекламой от Appodeal, как вы добавляли рекламу? Может быть, я что-то упускаю? Может быть, нужно выбрать 2-3 сети, а остальные их SDK удалить?

Answer (score -1):

Привет! Не подскажешь какие именно форматы рекламы ты планируешь использовать в своем приложении? В зависимости от форматов рекламы в Вашем приложении, можно будет решить, какие рекламные сети стоит удалить из SDK.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/185402)

Comment: Если у вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/185402)